# Invalid JSON after calling Encoding.UTF8.GetString()

Tags: c#, json, utf-8, rabbitmq, nservicebus

I am trying to dequeue messages off of an `audit` queue that have been put there by the `NServiceBus` framework. The messages are Json Serialized and I am using RabbitMQ as a transport layer. As per the tutorials on the RabbitMQ site, I am doing the following:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare("audit", true, false, false, null);

        if (myType.IsNormalized()) { }

        var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
        channel.BasicConsume("audit", true, consumer);

        while (true)
        {
            var eventArgs = (BasicDeliverEventArgs) consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
            var body = eventArgs.Body;

            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

            var assemblyQualifiedName = String.Concat(eventArgs.BasicProperties.Type,
                        ", Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
            var objectType = Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedName);

            var deserializedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, objectType);
        }
    }
}
```

This runs fine up until the last line, where it promptly breaks and tells me the JSON is not valid. When I debug and check the content of message, the JSON looks fine to me, however the Visual Studio JSON visualizer claims it is not. What is more bizarre is if I copy the exact content from the debug session and hard code it in, then try to deserialize it, it works fine. If I copy the content into an online JSON validator, it confirms the JSON is valid.

So my question is whether `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` is doing something that can compromise my `message`? Is it introducing characters that might not be JSON friendly but could somehow be fixed via copy / paste.

The actual error thrown is: `{"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0."}`

EDIT: Below is a sample of the JSON returned by `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`

```
"{\"ProposalKey\":\"123-5\"}"
```

Corresponding to:

```
239 187 191 123 34 80 114 111 112 111 115 97 108 75 101 121 34 58 34 49 50 51 45 53 34 125
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the `JSON` before and after the `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`?

Comment: Posted a sample byte array / json combo

Comment: Are those `quote-escapes (\")` actually there, or are they quotes (`"`)? I recommend sending it to a `Console.WriteLine` or `Debug.Log` command to get the absolute string.

Comment: with what encoding  eventArgs.Body was encoded, for a try you can give a try with utf-16 or unicode.

Comment: @EBrown the console prints the following: `?{"ProposalKey":"123-5"}` which certainly explains what's wrong. . .but I am not sure what this means, since I cannot see that `?` in the debugger

Comment: Sounds like a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: See here for advice about stripping the BOM, if that's what it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915182/how-do-i-ignore-the-utf-8-byte-order-marker-in-string-comparisons

Comment: Those first three bytes in your output are **definitely** a UTF-8 Byte-Order Mark. (They correspond to HEX: `EF BB BF` which is the UTF-8 accepted BOM.) That's likely your issue. (I thought they looked familiar, did not recognize them in decimal form.) Of course, UTF-8, by definition, does not need a BOM. But that's not the point.

Comment: And also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317700/strip-byte-order-mark-from-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys, if someone wants to post an answer I will accept it