# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ?. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "param1": "someURL",
        "param2": "someURL2"
    },
    {
        "param1": "someURL3",
        "param2": "someURL4"
    }
]
```

[JsonLint](https://jsoncompare.com/#!/simple/fullscreen&reformat=none/) says that this JSON is valid.

Now I read this JSON file from Azure Storage download it to a stream and then encode it:

`string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());`

Next I want to deserialize this to a list of objects:

`List<MyParamObject> deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyParamObject>>(text);`

`MyParamObject` is a POCO with two attributes named `Param1` and `Param2`

When I try to deserialize it I get the following error:

`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ?. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

But I do give JsonConvert a string with a valid JSON what can I do?

Comment: does `content` look ok?

Comment: Your `memoryStream` must start with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  To handle the BOM use a `StreamReader` as shown in [How do I ignore the UTF-8 Byte Order Marker in String comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2915239/3744182) instead of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`.  In fact I think this is a duplicate.  If you agree I'll close it as such.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a HEX Editor I checked the beginning of the file and I found out that my IDE added a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the beginning of the file. So it looks like this:

ï»¿[..  {..    "

As they are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/5504438) I chose to get rid of them by creating a new file with Explorer/Finder and adding my JSON in there.