# Error - JObject Parse Error with [] in response

Tags: c#, json.net, console-application, httpresponse

Trying to parse:

```
[{"place_id":84979036,"licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","powered_by":"Map Maker: https://maps.co","osm_type":"node","osm_id":8358755414,"boundingbox":["35.8497801","35.8897801","-114.6800654","-114.6400654"],"lat":"35.8697801","lon":"-114.6600654","display_name":"Willow Beach, Mohave County, Arizona, United States","class":"place","type":"village","importance":0.47500000000000003}]
```

But the boundingbox:[] in the statement are causing errors, I can't get rid of them so I need to find a way to pull the lat and lon without getting this error.

Error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.'
```

Code:

```
bool PullGeoJson(string city, string state, out string[] output)
{
    HttpResponse<string> response = UnirestLocationRequest(city, state);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ToString());
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(response.Body.ToString());
    output = new string[2];
    output[0] = json.GetValue("lat").ToString();
    output[1] = json.GetValue("lon").ToString();
    return !(output == null);
}
```

Comment: The JSON you posted appears to be create (hint: format it to be human friendly). Therefore I suggest that the body is not quite what you have pasted. What *exactly* is returned from `response.Body.ToString()`? (If you are struggling to understand behaviour the biggest obstacle is often your own assumptions about what works: check *everything*!)

Comment: Maybe the body is including a BOM? In which case see https://stackoverflow.com/q/51848925/67392

Comment: Well, obviously it's not just a json object you got, the [`[` and `]`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) should have told you as much. Parse the json data as what it _**is**_, not as what you want it to be (because it is not what you want it to be). Then, after parsing, get/extract the desired data from the parsed result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model that contains the structure of the response you're expecting then deserialize into the model:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string city = "Pense";
    string state = "Canada";
    HttpResponse<string> response = Unirest.get("https://geocode.maps.co/search?q=" + city + "," + state).asJson<string>();

    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GeoModel>>(response.Body.ToString());
}

public partial class GeoModel
{
    [JsonProperty("place_id")]
    public long PlaceId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lat")]
    public string Lat { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lon")]
    public string Lon { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: There's no need to create a model - if the OP is happy doing it dynamically, all they need to do is use `JArray.Parse` instead of `JObject.Parse`.