# UTF-8 remove BOM

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8

I have an XML file with a UTF-8 BOM in the beginning of the file, which hinders me from using existing code that reads UTF-8 files.

How can I remove the BOM from the XML file in an easy way?

Here I have a variable `xmlfile` in `Byte` type that I convert to `string`. `xmlfile` contains the entire XML file.

```
 byte[] xmlfile = ((Byte[])myReader["xmlSQL"]);

 string xmlstring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xmlfile);
```

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't use `XMLReader` at all - does that code fail, or is it some of the code you haven't shown us? What does the exception look like? I'd expect XMLReader to handle BOMs anyway...

Comment: sorry good question. no xmlreader is just part a function that reads over the content of the xml file to find namespaces. that works fine, my problem is that i cant read utf-8bom files. because of these character infront  of the file. so i need to remove those so i can use xmlreader. So its either with xmlfile as byte or xmlstring as a string to remove BOM

Comment: Please edit your question to make it *much* clearer. Ideally, provide a [mcve]. "i cant read utf-8bom files" really doesn't give us *nearly* enough information about the error you're facing. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions on how to write a good question.

Comment: Don't use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`, instead use a `StreamReader`, it consumes the BOM automatically.  as shown in [Encoding.UTF8.GetString doesn't take into account the Preamble/BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11701341/3744182) and [How do I ignore the UTF-8 Byte Order Marker in String comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2915239/3744182).  Even better, you could pass the `StreamReader` directly to the `XmlReader` and avoid the waste of the intermediate `xmlstring` representation.  Or pass a `MemoryStream` containing the bytes to the `XmlReader` that should also consume the BOM.

Comment: the XML file is saved as xmlfile and later converted to xmlstring as a string. can you remove the BOM characters from either ?

Comment: Use `myReader.GetXmlReader`. And don't forget to dispose everything with `using`. This is obviously assuming you are actually storing it in the database as `xml` type, because you are, right.....?

Comment: Great stuff DBC :) that worked well ! To fix my problem i just added the content to memory stream and then streamreader. and it removed the BOM.

Comment: @Beefybanana - glad to help.  Close as a duplicate of [Encoding.UTF8.GetString doesn't take into account the Preamble/BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11701341/3744182) then?

Comment: i should close it ? i did change the text. seems very readable now

Answer (score 2):

Great stuff DBC :) that worked well with your link. To fix my problem where i had a UTF-8 BOM tag in the beginning of my xml file. I simply added memorystream and streamreader, which automaticly cleanced the the xmlfile(htmlbytes) of BOM elements.
Really easy to implement for existing code.

```
 byte[] htmlbytes = ((Byte[])myReader["xmlMelding"]);
 var memorystream = new MemoryStream(htmlbytes);
 var s = new StreamReader(memorystream).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Encoding.GetString()` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Encoding_GetString_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) that accepts an offset into the `byte[]` array.  Simply check if the array starts with a BOM, and if so then skip it when calling `GetString()`, eg:

```cs
byte[] xmlfile = ((Byte[])myReader["xmlSQL"]);
int offset = 0;

if (xmlfile.Length >= 3 &&
    xmlfile[0] == 0xEF &&
    xmlfile[1] == 0xBB &&
    xmlfile[2] == 0xBF)
{
    offset += 3;
}

string xmlstring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xmlfile, offset, xmlfile.Length - offset);
```

Comment: **change last byte** _xmlfile[1] == 0xBF_  to **xmlfile[2] == 0xBF** just work fine. Thanks